# getting exception when inserting events in android calendar

Tags: android, calendar, gdata-api, gdata

i am inserting events in my android calendar. the code is following:

```
ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
    event.put("calendar_id", calId);
    event.put("title", "Event Title");
    event.put("description", "Event Desc");
    event.put("eventLocation", "Event Location");
    event.put("allDay", 1);
    event.put("eventStatus", 1);
    event.put("visibility", 0);
    event.put("transparency", 0);
    event.put("hasAlarm", 1);

    Date d = new Date();
    d.setHours(8);
    d.setMinutes(30);
    d.setSeconds(30);
    long startTime = d.getTime();
    d.setHours(12);
    d.setMinutes(30);
    d.setSeconds(20);
    long endTime = d.getTime();
    event.put("dtstart", startTime);
    // event.put("dtend", endTime);
    event.put("rrule", "FREQ=DAILY;WKST=SU");
    // event.put("lastDate", endTime);
    // event.put("timezone", "Asia/Karachi");
    //event.put("duration", "P3600S");

    //Calendar gmtC = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Karachi"));



    // event.put("transparency", 0);
    // event.put("hasAlarm", 1); // 0 for false, 1 for true
    Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
    Uri url = getContentResolver().insert(eventsUri, event);
```

i am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: allDay is true but sec, min, hour are not 0.
```

need help!

Comment: The content provider you are using is not part of the Android SDK. Your code will break on some devices that do not include the AOSP Calendar application or have modified it. Your code may break in future versions of Android. Please use the Google GData API for manipulating the user's calendar.

Comment: dear i know all these things but i currently need resolve this issue.

Comment: To resolve the issue, use the Google GData API for manipulating the user's calendar.

Comment: till now Google GData  not supported the Calendar A?I. you can check the following link :http://code.google.com/p/android-gdata/
android gdata under development.

Comment: you dont need "android-gdata" its an open protocol. The link is not a google project. http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide.html is the docs on calendar-gdata. if the java library doesnt work, not sure if it will, then you can implement the needed parts of the protocol - http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html

Comment: It's not all day if it doesn't start at midnight... then it's only part of a day.  8:30 to 12:30 is not all day.

Comment: @CommonsWare Hi  How you solved the issue, I found an ansewr by Rob, is that correct do we have to give start and end time as same for all day

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem, even with hours, minutes and seconds set to 0. Then I discovered, that for allday events, the times have to be set in UTC. This means, you need to add the UTC offset of the calendar's timezone to your allday event start time.

For example: (timezone and startTime are only hardcoded for simplification purposes!)

```
// You should write a method to get the calendar's timezone through a query
String calendarTimezone = "CET";

// Start time of the event. Hours, minutes and seconds have to be 0.
long startTime = 1315087200000L; // equals 2011-09-04 00:00:00

// Get UTC offset for the given timezone and start time. This way DST is accounted for.
int timeZoneOffset = TimeZone.getTimeZone(calendarTimezone).getOffset(startTime);

// Set same time for start and end of the allday event. Add UTC offset.
event.put("dtstart", startTime + timeZoneOffset);
event.put("dtend", startTime + timeZoneOffset);
event.put("allDay", 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The calendar GData API defines an all day event with a start time of just the date, and the end time of the day after the end of the event.

This is the data sent to google data api

```
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
    xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>

  <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind'
    term='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event'></category>
  <title type='text'>Word of the Day</title>
  <gd:when startTime='2007-07-17'
    endTime='2007-07-18'></gd:when>

</entry>
```

Notice the start/end times do not contain any time information in them.

You CANNOT have an all day event that doesn't start at midnight. That is why you are getting the exception. hour, min, sec MUST be 0 for them on an all day event.

You can try another forum, but you will always get this answer because this is how the GData API works.

Comment: how can i use the code you mention above. kindly provide me the sample code if you have.

Comment: version 2.0 of the gdata library supports android. http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/ you can get it there. and the docs are at http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html

Comment: thanks for reply. i worked on gdata libraries but from there i concluded till now gdata not supported on android. Did you try it on android?

Comment: what is not working? you add the library to your project and you use the library to make the "api calls". the docs have sample code on how to do everything with the api.

Comment: you may check out the sample code present in the gdata. from there you will find that it is for java not for android.i have tried it.

Comment: if you comments out the event.put("rrule", "FREQ=DAILY;WKST=SU"); line present in my post you will easily add the all day events in the calendar widget. but the problem in rrule property. Calendar using vCalendar. i think problem in vCalendar.

Comment: yes, it is for "java" and android apps are written in java. it looks like i linked you to the wrong library. sorry, http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/ that is the gdata library that supports android.

Comment: android is a java but android have their own sdk. there are certain java packages not supported in android.kindly my suggestion you will search it out.

Comment: if you look at the last link i gave you, it specifically states that it is for android. I know they have their own sdk. that is why i corrected my link from the first one i sent you. - http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/ this is the android supported client.

Answer (score 1):

If allDay is set to 1 eventTimezone must be TIMEZONE_UTC and the time must correspond to a midnight boundary, means hour , minute , second should be zero of calendar object.

refer following link..

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Events.html

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));           
cal.set(2014, 03, 18, 0, 0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

you specify "allDay" as true, but you set a time with sec, min and hour. Which means for the system, taht it's not all day long... try removing either allDay or the time setting. Maybe these are opposite and contradictory.

Comment: Ok, I expect the  same answer from this forum. I know that I am able to add simple events in the calendar. But I want to add whole day recurrence event.  Now I will try some other forum.

Answer (score 0):

rob is correct! You have to define allday events in UTC.
The following code is a little bit nicer than robs version:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    long dtstart = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    builder.withValue(Events.DTSTART, dtstart);
```